# Changing Assembly Name break Blazor WebAssembly Web app

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly

I just create a default Blazor wasm project and I need to change the assembly name of it. However, it break the web app. It can still run but the component from App.razor seem not loading.

For example : The Index page should look like this
[image: Expected Index page]

However, when I change the assembly name from default name **$(MSBuildProjectName)** to **MyAssembly.$(MSBuildProjectName)** then the index page will become like this .Can anyone help me to fix this please. Thanks

[image: Index page when change Assembly]

Comment: how did you change the assembly name? Did you do it inside of the IDE and rename or manually in file explorer?

Comment: And always mention if you did a Ctrl+F5 already.

Comment: Hi @RBee , so in my solution I add Directory.Build.props file where I specify the AssemblyName is   "MyAssembly.$(MSBuildProjectName)" . It will make all projects in my solution has MyAssembly prefix to its default Assembly name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, either perform a `dotnet clean` or delete the bin and obj folders.

Then, in your `wwwroot\index.html` file. Rename your [Blazor bundled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/css-isolation?view=aspnetcore-7.0#css-isolation-bundling) stylesheet to match the assembly name prefix.

```
 <link href="MyAssembly.{YourProject}.styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```